# Занесение информации при нажатии на клавишу

Tags: php

Я делаю такую штуку:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `battle` (img,name,level,life,atk,def,type,username) SELECT img,name,level,life,atk,def,type,username FROM `enemy` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
```

Вот, и когда мы обновляем страницу добавляется новая запись. Как это убрать?

Comment: Удали код, который ты тут написал, и ничего никуда добавляться не будет :)))))

А, если без шуток, обновление и простой переход по ссылке на страницу для серверной стороны - это практически одно и тоже.

Comment: Так как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь условие, на повторную отправку формы. 
А если это не форма, то сложно ибо непонятно что ты там пишешь и зачем.
Опиши подробнее.